# R: Create Indicator Columns from list of conditions

Tags: r, indicator

I have a dataframe and a number of conditions. Each condition is supposed to check whether the value in a certain column of the dataframe is within a set of valid values.

This is what I tried:

```
# create the sample dataframe
age <- c(120, 45)
sex <- c("x", "f")

df <-data.frame(age, sex)

# create the sample conditions
conditions <- list(
  list("age", c(18:100)),
  list("sex", c("f", "m"))
)

addIndicator <- function (df, columnName, validValues) {
  indicator <- vector()

  for (row in df[, toString(columnName)]) {
    # for some strange reason, %in% doesn't work correctly here, but always returns FALSe
    indicator <- append(indicator, row %in% validValues)
  }
  df <- cbind(df, indicator)

  # rename the column
  names(df)[length(names(df))] <- paste0("I_", columnName)

  return(df)
}

for (condition in conditions){
  columnName <- condition[1]
  validValues <- condition[2]
  df <- addIndicator(df, columnName, validValues)
}

print(df)
```

However, this leads to all conditions considered not to be met - which is not what I expect:

```
  age sex I_age I_sex
1 120   x FALSE FALSE
2  45   f FALSE FALSE
```

I figured that `%in%` does not return the expected result. I checked for the `typeof(row)` and tried to boil this down into a minimum example. In a simple ME, with the same type and values of the variables, the `%in%` works properly. So, something must be wrong within the context I try to apply this. Since this is my first attempt to write anything in R, I am stuck here.

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: When you set `validValues` to `condition[2]`, your result is a list and not a vector; but you probably intended to feed your function with a vector. To extract the column values needed, try `validValues <- condition[[2]]` instead in your `for` loop. In addition, there is likely an easier or streamlined approach to establishing these indicators if interested...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer an approach that uses the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) family of packages:

```
library(tidyverse)

allowed_values <- list(age = 18:100, sex = c("f", "m"))

df %>%
  imap_dfr(~ .x %in% allowed_values[[.y]]) %>%
  rename_with(~ paste0('I_', .x)) %>%
  bind_cols(df)
```

`imap_dfr` allows you to manipulate each column in `df` using a lambda function. `.x` references the column content and `.y` references the name.

`rename_with` renames the columns using another lambda function and `bind_cols` combines the results with the original dataframe.

I borrowed the simplified list of conditions from ben's answer. I find my approach slightly more readable but that is a matter of taste and of whether you are already using the tidyverse elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

`conditions` appears to be a nested list. When you use:

```
validValues <- condition[2]
```

in your `for` loop, your result is also a list.

To get the vector of values to use with `%in%`, you can extract `[[` by:

```
validValues <- condition[[2]]
```

A simplified approach to obtaining indicators could be with a simple list:

```
conditions_lst <- list(age = 18:100, sex = c("f", "m"))
```

And using `sapply` instead of a `for` loop:

```
cbind(df, sapply(setNames(names(df), paste("I", names(df), sep = "_")), function(x) {
  df[[x]] %in% conditions_lst[[x]]
}))
```

**Output**

```
  age sex I_age I_sex
1 120   x FALSE FALSE
2  45   f  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using `across` and `cur_column()` (and leaning heavily on severin's solution):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(age = c(12, 45), sex = c('f', 'f'))
allowed_values <- list(age = 18:100, sex = c("f", "m"))

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(age, sex),
                c(valid = ~ .x %in% allowed_values[[cur_column()]])
                )
         )
```

Reference: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html#current-column

Related question: [Refering to column names inside dplyr's across()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62155957/refering-to-column-names-inside-dplyrs-across)