# Refering to column names inside dplyr's across()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is it possible to refer to column *names* in a lambda function inside `across()`?

```
df <- tibble(age = c(12, 45), sex = c('f', 'f'))
allowed_values <- list(age = 18:100, sex = c("f", "m"))

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(age, sex),
                c(valid = ~ .x %in% allowed_values[[COLNAME]])))
```

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151711/r-create-indicator-columns-from-list-of-conditions) where OP asks about validating columns in a dataframe based on a list of allowed values.

`dplyr` just gained `across()` and it seems like a natural choice, but we need columns names to look up the allowed values.

[The best I could come up with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62155334/965883) was a call to `imap_dfr`, but it is more cumbersome to integrate into an anlysis pipeline, because the results need to be re-combined with the original dataframe.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can refer to column names in `dplyr`'s `across`. You need to use `cur_column()`. Your original answer was so close! Insert `cur_column()` into your solution where you want the column name:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(age = c(12, 45), sex = c('f', 'f'))
allowed_values <- list(age = 18:100, sex = c("f", "m"))

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(age, sex),
                c(valid = ~ .x %in% allowed_values[[cur_column()]])
                )
         )
```

Reference: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html#current-column

Comment: Thanks.  `cur_column()` was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you may be asking too much of `across` at this point (but this may spur additional development, so maybe someday it will work the way you suggest).

I think that the `imap` functions from the purrr package may give you what you want at this point:

```
> df <- tibble(age = c(12, 45), sex = c('f', 'f'))
> allowed_values <- list(age = 18:100, sex = c("f", "m"))
> 
> df %>% imap( ~ .x %in% allowed_values[[.y]])
$age
[1] FALSE  TRUE

$sex
[1] TRUE TRUE

> df %>% imap_dfc( ~ .x %in% allowed_values[[.y]])
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  age   sex  
  <lgl> <lgl>
1 FALSE TRUE 
2 TRUE  TRUE
```

If you want a single column with the combined validity then you can pass the result through `reduce`:

```
> df %>% imap( ~ .x %in% allowed_values[[.y]]) %>%
+   reduce(`&`)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

This could then be added as a new column to the original data, or just used for subsetting the data.  I am not expert enough with the tidyverse yet to know if this could be combined with `mutate` to add the columns directly.